# Linux Home Firewall

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, firewall

I was recently delving into thoughts of building a small home server to run random things off of (maybe a TF2 server).  Thinking about this further I realized I would need to get a better firewall system for my current home network.  I was wondering what would be a good Linux distro to run for a home network firewall?

There are a ton of distro's out there, and it is kinda overwhelming when you're new to it. I have looked at Zentyal (previously eBox), SmoothWall, M0n0wall and a couple others.  I have little experience in setting up firewalls, but I am willing to do some research into it and give it a shot.  I would just like a little help with the starting ground. If someone could provide some pro's/con's of available distro's or some insight on what might be best to set up in a home network it would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distro called **ipcop** exists since 2007 and is designed exactly for your purpose.
http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ipcop

I think there are many reasons strongly in favor of ipcop that put it ahead of the bunch:

1. Designed for your purpose
2. Long history + high ranking in google search "linux firewall distro"
3. Latest release: 2012 February

As the other post mentions, pfsense can be interesting to, a big difference is that pfsense (like moonwall) is based on FreeBSD, not on Linux.

Comment: I reviewed (most of) the manual for ipcop and it does seem like a decent linux firewall distro, however my concern is that it does seem to rely on mostly dated hardware (it still speaks of floppy disks as a main boot source).  Have you used ipcop?  Would you say it is still reliable?   I do like the ease of use for the web interface for it, and their classification of each zone in a network (Red, Blue, Green, Orange).

Comment: Hi @SirCobalt, nope, haven't actually used it. I keep an eye on the various distros and have my list of options for specific purposes, and ipcop is my top candidate for firewall, but that's all.